# Unpacking number is resulting in out of order

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit-manipulation

I have the following variable:

```
const input = [0x0001000200030004]
```

And I have a function to unpack four numbers from 1 (it cames from a C++ code, where I have four int16_t that are packed into a single uint64_t)

```
export function unpack(input: number[]) {
  const output: number[] = []

  for (const packed of input) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const num = (packed >> (i * 16)) & 0xffff

      const signedNum = num < 0x8000 ? num : -(0x10000 - num)

      output.push(signedNum)
    }
  }

  return output
}
```

The function kind works; however, it is out of order.

Instead of the output being [1, 2, 3, 4], it is [1, 2, 4, 3].

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `0x0001000200030004` is too large to be represented as a 32 bit integer

Comment: @jcalz No, `Number.isSafeInteger(0x0001000200030004)` is `true`.

Comment: @jcalz No it's not, but only barely because of the leading zeroes

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `unpack([0x0001000200030004])` returns `[4, 3, 4, 3]`, not `[1, 2, 4, 3]`

Comment: 0x0001000200030004 is too large to be represented as a 32 bit integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has already been identified in the comments and in @Unmitigated's answer (namely that bitwise operators work on 32 bit numbers in JS, which cannot represent your uint64), but a better solution is to use a [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array) and a [`Int16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array) as views on the same buffer for the conversion:

```js
function unpack(input) {
  const buffer = new BigUint64Array(input).buffer;
  return Array.from(new Int16Array(buffer));
}

console.log(unpack([0x0001000200030004n]))
```

However, you might need a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) to control endianness, which might be different than the one of the platform where your C++ code is executed.

Comment: Was thinking of something similar, especially `Int16Array` bit, but first loading a buffer with `BigUint64Array` first, nice.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that bitwise operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers first (unless working with `BigInt`s). But `0x0001000200030004` cannot be represented using 32 bits, so the code does not work properly. The solution is to simply use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s for all operations instead.

You would also need to reverse the order of iteration or reverse the output at the end to get the most significant digits first.

```js
function unpack(input) {
  const output = [];
  for (const packed of input) {
    for (let i = 3n; i >= 0n; i--) {
      const num = (packed >> (i * 16n)) & 0xffffn;
      const signedNum = num < 0x8000n ? num : -(0x10000n - num);
      output.push(signedNum);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(unpack([0x0001000200030004n]).map(x => x.toString()));
```